# how to convert $(#someid) in angularjs with same dom structure as a result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Web</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div class="dynamic-content" >No data  Yet
                <!-- Loading content Here -->
            </div>
            <button ng-click="loadTemplate()">Load Template</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            
            app.config(
                function( $controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider ) {
                   
                    app.controller = function(  app, TempCtl ) {
                        $controllerProvider.register(  app, TempCtl);
                        return( this );
                    };
                   
                }
            );
      
        
            app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope,$compile) {
                $scope.someData = {};
                $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
                   container =$(".dynamic-content"); 
                   
                    container.html('<div ng-controller="TempCtrl" my-Dir><h2>About</h2> <h3>{{total}}</h3> <p>Testing the total</p> <button ng-click="update()">Update</button> </div> <script> console.log("begin"); console.log(app.controller); app.controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) { $scope.total = 0; console.log("inside"); $scope.update = function () { $scope.total = $scope.total + 1; }; }); console.log("end") <\/script></div>');                  
                    $compile(container)($scope)
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


template.html:-

<div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>{{total}}</h3>
    <p>Testing the total</p>
    <button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>

<script>
    console.log("begin")
    angular.module("app")
    .controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.total = 0;
        console.log("inside")
        $scope.update = function () {
            total += total;
        };
    });
    console.log("end")
</script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/kwztb0PfoR4ShzY6rz3k?p=preview

iam trying to compile  my dom with script dynamically which  contains controller by name TestCtrl in which i  have a code which increments on click of update,though its working perfectly fine i have used `jquery($(.dynamic-content))` code to achieve it which must be replaced by either angularjs or javascript code i have already tried but it didnt work.Can you please give some suggesion?below is my plunker link have a go through.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$document.find()` if I am not mistaken? [Link to API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: You can create directive for template and call it as attribute or inside of '.dynamic-content' class's div

Comment: in container.html() my html code is loaded dynamically from api so i can use directive for that

Comment: jquery link has to be removed that's the reason i want to achieve that by purely angularjs i have tried with  some jqlite methods like find,$element,$document but could not achieve

Answer (score 0):

Angular has built-in `JQLite` support and a number of `DOM` traversal functions attached to it.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

For your case - `angular.element` will not find elements through css selectors. But you can do either of the followings:

- Use `jqLite` functionalities **[** *which are more like `jQuery` but limited -- like for DOM traversal `jqLite` methods are `children()`, `parent()`, `contents()`, `find()`, `next()`, etc.* **]**
- Use `jQuery` js file along with angular and do the normal `jQuery` operations. It is supported and practiced.
- Use `angular.element` methods - of course which are similar to `jQuery` methods with some exceptions.
- Use standard `DOM` APIs, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll()` or similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

While I really think you should follow Shailendra's advice, I think it's important to note a couple of things.

Namely, if you're including jQuery in your project anyway, `angular.element()` returns the same thing as the jQuery `$()` function.

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

Because you were including jQuery after you were including the Angular library, the `angular.element` was defaulting to the subset of jQuery that angular uses called jqLite. Literally all I did in [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pyd1QmAo5duTcZ7pqizP?p=preview) was switch the order your libraries were added in so that jQuery was added first.

### Note

**Code Below will not work, please see the plunkr link for a full demo. This is due mostly to the fact that I can never get angular to work with the snippet editor.**

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.config(
   function($controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider) {

     app.controller = function(app, TempCtl) {
       $controllerProvider.register(app, TempCtl);
       return (this);
     };

   }
 );


 app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
   $scope.someData = {};
   $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
     container = angular.element(".dynamic-content");

     container.html('<div ng-controller="TempCtrl" my-Dir><h2>About</h2> <h3>{{total}}</h3> <p>Testing the total</p> <button ng-click="update()">Update</button> </div> <script> console.log("begin"); console.log(app.controller); app.controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) { $scope.total = 0; console.log("inside"); $scope.update = function () { $scope.total = $scope.total + 1; }; }); console.log("end") <\/script></div>');
     $compile(container)($scope);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container body-content">
  <div class="dynamic-content">No data Yet
    <!-- Loading content Here -->
  </div>
  <button ng-click="loadTemplate()">Load Template</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i have to achieve it without jquery link,my code should be purely based on angularjs.so any suggesstions

Comment: then you're going to need to use the `$document` provider and the `$document.find()` function.

Comment: i have used it but its unable to parse controller showing message TempCtrl is not defined

Comment: could be please check and let me know where it went wroung

Comment: this is purely for my own knowledge, but is there any reason you don't use jQuery for this project?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kqkbeHXkANOBHgpQw5IY?p=preview here is my link after using $document.find() but still  could not achieve it

Comment: because that the clients requirement so have to do it

Comment: any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I've got nothing as of right now. Hopefully someone else who knows more about the ins and outs of angular can help you on this one. I tried to use the javascript `document.querySelector` but I get some error that makes no sense to me personally.